# How to tell if this sequence converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence, gradient-descent

I have a function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^4$, where $x = 1$ initially. Every time step, the function is updated with the rule $x = x - \alpha * dx$. I want to know if the function will converge to 0 at $t = \infty$ and if so, for what ranges of the scalar $\alpha$.

I know $dx = 2x^3$ and this problem sort of reminds me of a combination of geometric/arithmetic series, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I wrote a Python script to try out different values, but I was hoping to have a more analytic solution.

```
def dx(x):
  return 2 * x ** 3

def fx(x):
  return 0.5 * x ** 4

i = 0
x = 1
alpha = 0.9
while i < 20:
  x -= alpha * dx(x)
  print("{}: {}".format(i, x))
  i += 1
```

I would really appreciate some advice on how to approach this problem.

Comment: If $x_n$ is the value at $t =n$, then $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \alpha dx_n = x_n - 2 \alpha x_n^3 = x_n(1 - 2 \alpha x_n^2)$$. This is a multiple of $x_n$. Under what conditions is the factor $<1$?

Comment: @HansEngler thanks for the response! Wouldn't it depend on both the value of $\alpha$ and $x_n$?

Comment: Yes it would. So now you have to use $x_1 = 1$.

Comment: So for $x_2$, you would get $x_2 = x_1(1 - 2 \alpha x_1^2) = (1 - 2\alpha)$. This leads me to believe that $\alpha \in [0, 0.5)$ because this would scale $x_n$ by a factor between [0, 1). However, if $\alpha$ were 0.6, this would scale it by a factor of -0.2, which still shrinks it, but now does so from the negative side. This leads me to believe that $\alpha$ can be in the range (-0.5, 0.5).

Comment: Note that $\alpha$ cannot be 0, so your range is not quite right. Also work with $|x_n|$ instead of $x_n$, then everything becomes easier.